# Maven module doesn't inherit xml file

Tags: maven

I have three maven modules in my webapp. The second one depends on the first
module and the third one depends on the second module (**F <= S <= T**).

First module contains spring configuration file in *META-INF.spring* folder, so does the second one.

The third module is supposed to extend the second one and must have the same spring configuration file, so it doesn't contain any configuration files, and I expect maven to extract it from the second module.

But when I run "**clean package**" the third module appears to contain the configuration file form the *FIRST* module.

The question is why is that happening and what should I do?

[Graphical description of the problem](http://gyazo.com/08c7e9dc089726cbed3c992298763106)
[Pom files of the project](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GnD1B3uH1ktnqBoRoWtENN0UMo_M30ss4iRDrASF96c/edit)

Comment: show us you pom please

Comment: Which one? :) There are three pom's for the modules and one more for the whole project, it's too much to post here

Comment: How do you extract the config file in the third module?

Comment: I just have a dependency on the second module (And in the next comment I'll provide all the poms in google doc :)

Comment: [Here are all the poms](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GnD1B3uH1ktnqBoRoWtENN0UMo_M30ss4iRDrASF96c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: So two jars contain files with the same name and Spring finds the wrong one? Your best bet is probably to prevent this name clash. Otherwise you might solve it by ensuring that the second jar is coming first in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in maven-dependency-plugin phase tag contained

```
<phase>package</phase>
```

and with

```
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
```

everything works fine now :)